# Script to convert many binary files to ASCII

Tags: bash, find

I'd like to run a script, say `convert.py` (which converts binary to ascii, but outputs to stdout) on 30 or so `*.gz` files, but instead of output going to screen, it goes to a *.txt file, similar to so:

```
convert.py jonny.gz > jonny.txt
```

How would I do it with a `for` loop or `find` command?

Comment: Are all the `.gz` files in the same directory - or are they buried in different subdirectories?

Comment: they are in the same directory

Comment: i thought i should be able to use a single find command, still trying to figure the syntax out

Comment: @Zanna While “converting binary files to ASCII” might describe what the (not included) script does, I think the title [suggested by Mathieu](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1168987/2) better expressed what the question is about.

Comment: @Melebius that title is a dupe of something. If there's any non-generic about the question that might suggest potential answers, shouldn't it be in the title?

Answer (score 3):

Simple `for` loop:

```
for f in ./*.gz; do
    convert.py "$f" > "${f%.gz}.txt"
done
```

Using the `find` command:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.gz' -exec sh -c 'convert.py "$1" > "${1%.gz}.txt"' sh {} \;
```

or

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.gz' -exec sh -c '
  for f; do convert.py "$f" > "${f%.gz}.txt"; done
' sh {} +
```

(there's really no advantage to using `find` in this case).

Comment: Thanks steeldriver, when i put the for loop (decided to use that) in a shell script, it creates the *.txt file, but doesn't do the convert python script, cause the script completes, but the file is empty

Comment: when i run the for loop from the command line, it works great thanks man!